# Safari - position:fixed doesn't breaks element from scope

Tags: html, css, safari

I found a weird Safari behavior related to positioning.

For example:

```
#parent {
  position:fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height:30px;
}
#toolTip-child {
  position:fixed
  display:block;
  top:10px;
  left:16px;
  height:100px;
}
```

As far as I know, when position is set to fixed (or absolute, doesn't matter in that case), the element should be broken from the scope and render somehow independently.

It works as I mentioned above in every browser we use to tests the site we develop, beside of Safari.

In Safari, if parent element is `fixed` positioned and `overflow-x` property. is added, no matter how I position the child element (`position:fixed`, `top`, `left` -> doesn't matter), if it overflow the parent element, it's not visible.

I hitted the wall and have no idea how to force Safari to cooperate.

If anyone of you have any idea, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QVp3K/1/

Sorry for such delay, I couldn't redo this with fiddle. After half an hour I found out, that I had a type on "position".

Comment: Hm. The thing I'd be asking in this case is what you are really trying to achieve, as there may be a better way.

Comment: Well, there probably is. But first of all, I can't really mess with the code I have. It's huge html hack (including <thead> as display:block and other issues) in a huge application.

Secondly, I wonder, how come it is an issue anyway. Isn't Safari the same engine as Chrome? Shouldn't they behave  similar?

Comment: And, to give you some clue about the background. The `#toolTip-child` element toggles after a click action on table cell. It shows some action menu to a user. The parent of the cell is table head, which is positioned fixed to acquire a "frozen table head" workaround. I'm not huge fan of that kind of css hacks, but I have to live with it for now.

Comment: `Isn't Safari the same engine as Chrome?` No, not any more. Safari uses WebKit, while Chrome runs on Blink—which I think started as a fork of WebKit.

Comment: Rather than `overflow: hidden;` perhaps try positioning the hidden element way off screen and then move it back onscreen when clicked.

Comment: Hmm, but there is `overflow-x:hidden` for parent. It's always visible, with javascript scrollbar.

Comment: Over 2 years later, still a problem. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not actually an answer, because it seems like a bug, but I have a workaround.

The problem is that when we apply  `overflow-x:hidden` to an element, in Safari it also gets `overflow-y:hidden`. I don't know why, but it seems to be an ordinary bug.

Workaround I figured out is quite simple.

The child element toggling from `hidden` to `visible` state after click on the trigger. I simply added two lines. One resizes the parent element in y dimension. Second resizes it back when the child element hides.

Not the best solution, but is enough for me.